# Flatten a Linked List in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to flatten a multi level linked list.
Given a linked list where every node represents a linked list and contains two pointers of its type:
(i) Pointer to next node in the main list (we call it ‘right’ pointer in below code)
(ii) Pointer to a linked list where this node is head (we call it ‘down’ pointer in below code).
All linked lists are sorted

```
   5 -> 10 -> 19 -> 28
   |    |     |     |
   V    V     V     V
   7    20    22    35
   |          |     |
   V          V     V
   8          50    40
   |                |
   V                V
   30               45
```

TO

```
5 7 8 10 19 20 22 28 30 35 40 45 50
```

below is my Java code:

```
public class FlattenAList {
public static MultiNode<Integer> end = new MultiNode<Integer>(0);
public static MultiNode<Integer> result = end;

public static MultiNode flatten(MultiNode head) {
    if (head == null || head.right == null)
        return head;
    MultiNode<Integer> tmp = head;

    while (tmp != null) {
        merge(tmp, result);
        tmp = tmp.right;
    }
    return result;
}

public static void merge(MultiNode<Integer> a, MultiNode<Integer> b) {
    if (a == null) {
        end.down = b;
        end = end.down;
        return;
    }
    if (b == null) {
        end.down = a;
        end = end.down;
        return;
    }

    if (a.data <= b.data) {
        end.down = a;
        end = end.down;
        merge(a.down, b);
    } else {
        end.down = b;
        end = end.down;
        merge(a, b.down);
    }
}
}
```

The **merge function** is having problem, I am getting java.lang.StackOverflowError 
at java.lang.Integer.intValue(Unknown Source)

at **if (a.data <= b.data)**

Comment: What's the logic for you flattening? Describe it. For example there is a single `20` in the input and two in your output. There is a `28` in your input and it's absent from your output.

Comment: And the **explanation**? Currently this question will be closed as a "why isn't this code working" type question. You need to learn to use a debugger and  create an SSCCE. There is too much code here. And no explanation of what it's supposed to do.

Comment: It s supposed to flatten the the sorted list column wise, ck the desc above

Comment: So you want to do an inline flattening?

Comment: And where does `end` originate from?

Comment: From the description I'd expect the result to be `5 7 8 30 10 20 19 22 50 28 35 40 45` you seem to be merging and sorting not just **flattening**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fast easy way on how to do it according to your needs.

```
package example;

public class FlattenAList {

    private static MultiNode<Integer> merge(MultiNode<Integer> a, MultiNode<Integer> b) {
        MultiNode<Integer> head = new MultiNode<Integer>();
        MultiNode<Integer> temp = head;
        while (a != null && b != null) {
            if (a.data < b.data) {
                temp.down = a;
                temp = temp.down;
                a = a.down;
            } else if (b.data < a.data) {
                temp.down = b;
                temp = temp.down;
                b = b.down;
            }
        }

        temp.down = (a == null) ? b : a;
        return head.down;
    }

    static class MultiNode<T> {
        T data;
        MultiNode<T> right;
        MultiNode<T> down;

        public MultiNode(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public MultiNode() {

        }
    }

    public static MultiNode<Integer> flatten(MultiNode<Integer> root) {

        MultiNode<Integer> temp = root;
        MultiNode<Integer> result = null;
        while (temp != null) {
            result = merge(temp, result);
            temp = temp.right;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void print(MultiNode<Integer> start) {
        while (start != null) {
            System.out.print(start.data+" ");
            start = start.down;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiNode<Integer> start = new MultiNode<Integer>(5);
        start.right = new MultiNode<Integer>(10);
        start.right.right = new MultiNode<Integer>(19);
        start.right.right.right = new MultiNode<Integer>(28);

        start.down = new MultiNode<Integer>(7);
        start.down.down = new MultiNode<Integer>(8);
        start.down.down.down = new MultiNode<Integer>(30);

        start.right.down = new MultiNode<Integer>(20);

        start.right.right.down = new MultiNode<Integer>(22);
        start.right.right.down.down = new MultiNode<Integer>(50);

        start.right.right.right.down = new MultiNode<Integer>(35);
        start.right.right.right.down.down = new MultiNode<Integer>(40);
        start.right.right.right.down.down.down = new MultiNode<Integer>(45);
        // Node result = flatten(start);
        MultiNode<Integer> result = flatten(start);
        print(result);
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
5 7 8 10 19 20 22 28 30 35 40 45 50
```